# Consecutive Days count with specific credentials

Tags: mysql

I am working on a report where I work that will help our administration figure out vacation accrual.

If you work 40 hours consecutively, on the start of your 5th year, you get 10 hrs accrual and at the start of your 10th, you get 12. If you end up with a break, or you worked 40 hours, then went down to 20, then your time resets until you hit 40 again.

In my database, I have a field of "Job Progression" that gives the "Employee ID", the start date of the position and end date. The end date is `NULL` if they are currently employed.

These are some of the fields in my database I am working with:

```
+-----+-------+------------+------------+-------+    
| ID  | EmpID | startdate  | enddate    | hours |    
+-----+-------+------------+------------+-------+    
|   1 |     1 | 2011-06-01 | NULL       |    40 |   
|   2 |     2 | 2011-10-10 | NULL       |    40 |    
|   3 |     3 | 2000-03-01 | NULL       |    40 |    
|   5 |     5 | 1999-06-07 | NULL       |    40 |    
|   6 |     6 | 2012-05-16 | NULL       |    40 |    
|   7 |     7 | 1996-09-25 | NULL       |    40 |    
|   8 |     8 | 2015-10-07 | NULL       |    40    
|   9 |     8 | 2012-10-17 | 2015-10-06 |    40 |    
|  12 |     9 | 2000-06-05 | NULL       |    40 |
|  16 |    12 | 2005-08-04 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  17 |    13 | 2008-01-20 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  19 |    14 | 1999-02-17 | 2001-05-31 |    40 |    
|  22 |    16 | 2016-04-01 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  23 |    16 | 1999-11-01 | 2016-03-31 |    40 |    
|  29 |    18 | 1997-08-01 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  31 |    19 | 2012-02-13 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  36 |    22 | 2006-04-05 | NULL       |    40 |   
|  38 |    23 | 2015-07-01 | 2016-03-12 |    40 |    
|  44 |    27 | 2016-03-07 | 2017-03-03 |    40 |    
|  46 |    28 | 2002-11-11 | NULL       |    40 |    
|  47 |    29 | 2016-04-11 | NULL       |    40 |
```

So I need a query that looks at the users (`EmpID`) last consecutive full time (40 hours) and then checks to see how many years it has been.

Does this make sense or is it possible? I have seen a lot of examples where they do it with single dates, but none with date ranges.

When calculating this field, I have to be sure to only include the latest consecutive time at 40 hours. Consider this example:

An employee works 40 hours a week from 1/1/2016 - 10/1/2016, so they have 9 months of full-time hours. They then move to part-time from 10/2/2016 thru 1/1/2017. Then after this period, they go back to fulltime from 1/2/2017 thru 2/1/2017 to where they are promoted and then moved to another department, still full-time from 2/1/2017 through to today.

What we have to do is ignore the time they worked from 1/1/2016 - 10/1/2016 as when they went to part-time they lost their accrual. Now that they started again from 1/2/2017 thru now, we do have to include those in a calculation.

So the table would look like this:

```
+-----+-------+------------+------------+-------+--------+    
| ID  | EmpID | startdate  | enddate    | hours |  Title | 
+-----+-------+------------+------------+-------+--------+    
|   1 |     1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-10-01 |    40 | Job A  |  
|   2 |     1 | 2016-10-02 | 2017-01-01 |    20 | Job B  |   
|   3 |     1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01 |    40 | Job C  |
|   4 |     1 | 2017-02-02 | NULL       |    40 | Job D  |
+-----+-------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

So since ID 1 has a break at ID 2, it would not be calculated in the concurrent time, so the MySQL could only consider the time from record ID 3 & 4.

Then an output could be as easy as "EmpID - Diff Years." - so the Example above the correct output should be 1 - 0.8082 years

Comment: Sense? No. Possible? Surely. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/ZCD61464) for people to play with. I started to but bailed when I couldn't figure out the question.  Sample output would help.

Comment: So find the max(endDate) where hours < 40 for each employee.  then join back to base set to get only those records whose start date is > that employees end date (or all if no such max end date exists) then calculate teh difference in days for each job period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DVAG93376)  (May need to click run(F8) to see updates.)

I still don't know exactly what you're after...  the accrual rate for each employee? the number of years of consecutive 40 hour service depending on how we handle years and if summing the date diff works for leap years and what not...

```
SELECT EMPID
     , case when sum(yearsDiff) >= 5 and sum(yearsDiff) < 10 then 10
            when sum(yearsDiff) >= 10 then 12 end as AccrualRate
     , sum(yearsDiff) as CurrentConsecutive40HrYears
FROM (SELECT A.*
           , datediff(coalesce(endDate,curDate()),StartDate)/365 as YearsDiff
      FROM so46896406 A
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(endDate) AccStart, EmpID 
                 FROM SO46896406 
                 WHERE Hours < 40 
                 GROUP BY EmpID) B
        on A.EmpID = B.EmpID
      WHERE A.StartDate>=coalesce(B.AccStart,A.StartDate)
     )SUB
GROUP BY EmpID;
```

I use the suquery to find the max date of a job < 40 hours for an employee.  Then I use that as the earliest possible consecutive 40 hour range.  Then we sum all entries for an employee using date diff to see if the total range is > 5 years and < 10 and assign 10 as the rate.  if > 10, then  12 is the rate.  Anything below 5 is a NULL rate.

I added empID 30 using your new data since I didn't want to repeat the 1 in the original set. and it comes out as .8082 as you have.  which results in null for accrual rate, since it's < 5 years required to have an accrual of 10.

The coalesce(b.AccStart,A.StartDate) simply says keep all records whose start date is > the max non-40 hour date; but if an employee never had a 40 hour date; just return all records for that employee.

Now we could simplify the where clause to:
`WHERE B.AccStart is null OR A.StartDate >=B.AccStart;`  since we only want records for employyee who never have worked less than 40; or those that have worked less; but we only want their records after the date having less than 40.

Both of these records achieve the same result; but the `WHERE A.StartDate>=coalesce(B.AccStart,A.StartDate)` should be more efficient as it avoids the double index search on A.StartDate due to the or.

Comment: This do it? or am i still not getting the question?

Comment: Hi xQbert, This is exactly what I am looking for! :) While I don't understand 100% of how you did it (i just need to re-read through your explanation), this is exactly the end result I needed. I am new to StackOverFlow and not 100% sure how to say your answer was exactly what I was looking for. I did the green checkmark.

Comment: Green checkmark says this answer met your requirements.  Ask questions if you don't understand something I'll try and explain it.  I'd be careful with leap years and how we're calculating if someone is at 10 or 12.  Those edge cases may cause your problems over time.  I was also unsure how to report < 5 so Null I hope is acceptable (but easy enough for you to change)

Comment: Is there a better way to handle Leap years? Maybe instead of doing days could it be calculated with Months?

Comment: Leap years are a common problem you either have to do some really fancy logic to determine which ranges have leap years and how many  and then add the 365*(years of service less leap years) + 366*years of leapyearService)  or just accept the limitation and treat all years the way mySQL does (and I'd have to check I don't recall. The  mySQL date math may take it into account automatically)  However, it wouldn't be able to do so when we're summing across multiple entries.  Just depends on level of accuracy needed (maybe the HR method says it treats all years as 365 for accrual purposes?)

Comment: Alot of words to say, if you have to have it we can likely figure it out; but lets find out what the REQUIREMENT is before we jump through those hoops.  I wanted to make sure you understood the limitations of this answer.   By summing the % of a year on each record we may get imprecise values over time.  thus is the nature of dealing with date segments.

Comment: Another question is I notice you have "WHERE Hours < 40." Shouldn't this be = 40 to rule out anything less than 40 hours? or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: In short no.  The inner query `SELECT max(endDate) AccStart, EmpID 
                 FROM SO46896406 
                 WHERE Hours < 40 
                 GROUP BY EmpID` returns only employees who have hours < 40 (not full time) along with the most recent occurrence of this.  We then use that date as the EARLIEST date we can consider calculating accruals which is what the line `WHERE A.StartDate>=coalesce(B.AccStart,A.StartDate)` then does. This way we eliminate all the time before a consecutive range of 40 hours.

Comment: Using the example: The inner most query identifies the end date `2017-01-01` for employeeID 1 as the earliest possible start date for a consecutive range of 40 hours.  Since it's the Highest date that isn't 40 hours.    So the query aliased 'sub'  returns records 3,4 from your last example, while eliminating 1,2.  but since we also keep all employee records who didn't have a < 40 hour job, we can then sum.  I'll break apart the rextester example so it shows this better.

Comment: The [Demo](http://rextester.com/edit/DVAG93376) has been updated ot break out the SQL into  3 selects so you'll see 3 tables below and a #comment has been added as a lead in to each SQL block to better explain what is going on and hopefully why.  You'll note I added comment blocks to try and explain what each step does and why.

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work.

```
select EmpID, 
case when enddate is null then (DAY(now()) - DAY(startdate))/365
     else (DAY(enddate) - DAY(startdate))/365
end as diff_years
from yourTable
where hours=40
group by EmpId
having max(startdate);
```

[Click here for Demo](http://rextester.com/RGKU44136)
Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a start, but I have to be sure to only include the latest consecutive data and not the range. - I am editing my post to include an example.

Comment: I guess `having max(startdate)` will only calculate most recent years as Full time & that's what you want. So what is the output you're getting for my query?

Comment: Looks like I am just getting a 1, which is close to what I am looking for. I would need it to be a little more specific, like the 0.8.

Comment: I need to brush up more on my SQL! :P I figured this would have been a very complex answer with a lot of @variables and such...not as easy as doing "having max(startdate)" :P

Comment: I looked through the demo and it looks like it still isn't considering concurrent dates. If you look at EmpID 16, in the answer it shows "0,0603" for an answer, but they have had 1/11/1999 => 03/31/2016 as full time, then 04/01/2016 => now. So their answer should be 18.79 years